# how to make password >7 characters (validation)?

Tags: php, forms, passwords

I have a form, but I am having trouble getting the strlen function to work.
Below is an example of the code - there is validation further down.
I've commented out the code that isn't working. Basically, all I want to do with this section of code is determine that the passwords match, and are more than 7 characters long.

Can anyone help?

```
if (isset($_POST['formName']) && $_POST['formName'] == "addUser") {

if ( ( $_POST['frmName'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmSurname'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmEmail'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmPassword1'] != '') ) {


    if ($_POST['frmPassword1'] != $_POST['frmPassword2'] )  {

        echo "Passwords do not match!";
    } 

/*  if (strlen( ($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 7 ) {

        echo "Passwords much be a minimum of 7 characters"; 
    } */
```

Comment: that strlen line has 3 `(` and only 2 `)`, so it's an outright syntax error if you uncomment it.

Comment: Also are `formName` and `frmName` different fields???

Comment: `if (strlen($_POST['frmPassword1']) > 7 )`

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: *Preemptive strike...* **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: agree Jay, I hate when someone tells me how my passord should look. It always means I forget it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where its messed up:

```
if (strlen( ($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 7 ) {
```

Let's start that statement over.

First you want the string represented by form field frmPassword1:

```
$_POST['frmPassword1']
```

Then you want the string length:

```
strlen($_POST['frmPassword1'])
```

*Then you want to **compare it to less than 8** because you specifically asked for more than 7 characters*. Therefore, your expression would be:

```
strlen($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 8
```

Now make that a complete condition like so:

```
if( strlen($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 8 ){
 //insert relevant code here telling users password is too short
}
```

Now you have a working block of code.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your ():

```
strlen( ($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 7 )
      a b                      b     a
      ^-----strlen-------------------^
```

You're not testing the length of the $_POST value, you're doing strlen on the boolean result of `foo < 7`, which will always be 0/1:

```
php > var_dump(strlen(true), strlen(false));
int(1)
int(0)
```

YOu need:

```
if (strlen($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 7) {
   a      b                      b    a
```

Note the labels on the `()`.

Comment: Are you sure about the 1 in: `if (strlen($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 1)` ? ;-)

Comment: well, maybe I like my password really simple... heh. Thanks...fixed.

Comment: Easy to remember for sure

Answer (score 0):

You are missing end `)`

```
if (strlen( ($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 7 ) {
   1      2  3                     3     2  # 1 is missing
```

So it would be

```
if (strlen( ($_POST['frmPassword1']) < 7 ) ){
   1      2  3                     3     2 1
```

---

> > > **NOTE :** In your question you have mentioned **that passwords match, and are more than 7 characters**. So use `<=` (less than or equal).

Comment: Nope.. he got one ( too much

Comment: @Andreas Its not prob. Closing is the cause

Comment: Ok sure.. that may be true, but what is the point of the innermost ()? Nothing? Then it's one ( too much in my opinion

Comment: @Andreas that's your point of view. anyway thanks